# SQL GROUP BY with logical function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with data across multiple tables linked by a unique identifier for each person.

Let's say one table, called Eventstab contains a list of IDs and every time an event happened to that ID it lists the event next to that ID. Let's call the events "bought a potato", "fell off a chair", "watched a movie".

so Eventstab looks like

```
ID  | Event
----------------------    
200 | fell off a chair
200 | bought potato
200 | fell off a chair
500 | bought potato
```

So, as you can see - id 200 fell off a chair, 500 did not.

This Eventstab contains data for a SUBSET of the ids in the main data. We can conclude that if an ID appears in the main data, but not in Eventstab, they never fell off a chair.

The above information can be recovered with a query like:

```
SELECT id, event 
FROM thedatums 
JOIN Eventstab ON id 
WHERE ...
```

I am interested in finding, for each person in the dataset, whether they have ever fallen off a chair. I.E whether event = 'fell off chair' for that ID.

More specifically, i'd like a variable i'll call 'is_a_dimwit' that equals 1 if the id EVER has a record of 'fell off a chair' in Eventstab and 0 otherwise.

So in my head it's

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    CASE 
       WHEN event = 'fell off chair' THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS 'is_a_dimwit' 
FROM 
    thedatums 
JOIN 
    Eventstab ON id
```

EDIT: there are records where the ID is repeated with multiple 'fell off a chair'

However, I'd like each ID to be unique in my dataset and this 'is_a_dimwit' variable to measure if this person has EVER fallen off a chair in the data I have.

My question is twofold: how do I go about googling a potential answer to this? even better, how would you solve it?

Comment: I'm confused . . . what tables have which data?  Sample data and desired results would really help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I've attempted to rephrase and be more specific

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
select i.id,
       (case when exists (select 1 from thedatums where td.id = i.id and td.event = 'fell off chair')
             then 1
             when exists (select 1 from some_data where td.id = i.id and td.event = 'fell off chair')
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as is_a_dimwit
from ((select id from thedatums)
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select id from some_data)
     ) i;
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of case when exists, I think this might be how to go about the problem.